# Prove that if A is a square matrix with linearly indep columns, then $A^+$ = $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I have figured out a possible solution and I only need someone to tell me if I'm correct. The solution is the following:

If a matrix has linearly independent columns, then 
$A^+$ = $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

Therefore, by operating:
= $A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}A^T$ = $A^{-1}$ since $(A^T)^{-1}A^T = I$
So $A^+ = A^{-1}$

Am I right with this proof?

Thank you

Comment: How is $A^+$ defined?

Comment: More complete answers are given in the more complete form of your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318428/if-a-is-a-non-square-matrix-with-orthonormal-columns-what-is-a/2320169#2320169

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to assume that $A^+ = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, then your proof is indeed correct.

Comment: point taken. I am retracting the comment.